# list child pages of current parent with featured image and description

Tags: wordpress

Can someone show me how to list child pages of current page and include featured image and menu description? Here is what I've found so far, but I can't figure out how to get the descriptions to work.

```
    <ul>
    <?php $child_pages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent = ".$post->ID." AND post_type = 'page' ORDER BY menu_order", 'OBJECT');    ?>
    <?php if ( $child_pages ) : foreach ( $child_pages as $pageChild ) : setup_postdata( $pageChild ); ?>
    <li>
    <a href="<?php echo  get_permalink($pageChild->ID); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php echo $pageChild->post_title; ?>">
    <span class="thumbnail"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($pageChild->ID, 'small-thumb'); ?></span>
    <span class="title"><?php echo $pageChild->post_title; ?></span>
    </a>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; endif; ?>
    </ul>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "menu description"?

Comment: Appearance > Menus > Screen Options > Descriptions (checked). 

Then I see a textarea to add description to a selected menu item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up just using a custom field instead of the menu description. Here is the final code that worked for me.

```
  <?php 
  $args = array(
      'parent' => $post->ID,
      'post_type' => 'page',
      'post_status' => 'publish'
  ); 
  $pages = get_pages($args);  ?>
  <ul class="four no-bullets"> 
  <?php foreach( $pages as $page ) { ?>
   <li>
      <a href="<?php echo  get_permalink($page->ID); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php echo $page->post_title; ?>">
      <span class="thumbnail"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'small-thumb'); ?></span>
      <span class="title"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></span>
      <span class="desc"><?php echo get_post_meta($page->ID, 'desc', true); ?></span>
      </a>
  </li>
  <?php } ?>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try following code:

```
    <?php 
    $args = array(
        'parent' => 2,
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    ); 
    $pages = get_pages($args);  ?>
    <ul> 
    <?php
    foreach( $pages as $page ) {
    ?>
     <li>
        <a href="<?php echo  get_permalink($page->ID); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php echo $page->post_title; ?>">
        <span class="thumbnail"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'small-thumb'); ?></span>
        <span class="title"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></span>
        </a><span class="desc"><?php echo $page->post_content; ?></span>
    </li>
    <?php
     }  
    ?>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work. I replaced the snipped from the inital question with the code you provided but it only printed an empty <ul> </ul>

Comment: Have you replaced 'parent' => 2 with 'parent' => $post->ID ? . In given code you just need to change only this.

Comment: Awesome. Almost there, except instead of displaying the full post content for the description, is there a way to show the menu description?

Comment: @Bhumi Shah nice .. it working nicely. i have one question how to do charter limit for post content here `substr($post_content,0,25)` this not work i tried.